# Error in gsub(vn[i - 1], paste0("(", vars[[i - 1]], ")"), vars, fixed = TRUE) : invalid 'pattern' argument

Tags: r, yaml, gsub, decision-tree

I have been trying to built a decision tree and saved it as .yaml with the editor notepad++ as follows:

```
name: myTree
variables:
    costIM:3
    costKR250:2
    costKR500:1.5
    pdump:0.6
    pnodump:0.4
    cost0:(500*costIM)
    cost1a:(250*costIM+250*(costKR250+0.5*costKR250))
    cost2a:(250*costIM+250*2*costKR250)
    cost3a:(250*costIM+250*(costKR250+2*costKR250))
    cost4a:(250*costIM+250*costKR250)
    cost1b:(500*(costKR250+0.5*costKR250))
    cost2b:(500*2*costKR250)
    cost3b:(500*(costKR500+2*costKR500))
    cost4b:(500*costKR500)
    p13:1/3
type: decision
500IM:
    payoff: cost0  
250IMand250KR:
    type: chance
    DumpingCharge:
        p: pdump
        type: chance
        50%:
            p=p13
            payoff:cost1a
        100%:
            p=p13
            payoff:cost2a
        200%:
            p=p13
            payoff:cost3a
    NoDumpCharge:
        p: 1-pdump
            payoff:cost4a
500KR:
    type: chance
    DumpingCharge:
        p: pdump
        50%:
            payoff:cost1b
        100%:
            payoff:cost2b
        200%:
            payoff:
    NoDumpCharge:
        p: pnodump
            payoff:cost4b
```

Nevertheless when I try to plot it in R whith this code:

```
library(yaml)
tree = yaml.load_file(input ="C:\\Users\\camil\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\change.yaml")
result =dtree(yl = tree)
plot(result, final = T)
```

as I run "result..." I get this error: "Error in gsub(vn[i - 1], paste0("(", vars[[i - 1]], ")"), vars, fixed = TRUE) :   invalid 'pattern' argument"

What am I missing or doing wrong?

The same code worked for loading and plotting other decision trees in .yaml

Answer (score 0):

Probem solved: there were some missing spaces after ":".
yaml always require a space after :